# Check if a string contains some part of another string and return percentage

Tags: javascript

Here is a code to check the similarity percentage of two strings (`str1` and `str2` ). the code works fine and completely accurate. it logs a number between 0 to 1 based on similarities between two strings (it checks the similarities word by word).

So if we have these strings:

```
  var str1 = "I was sent to earth to protect you"; // user input
  var str2 = "I was sent to earth to protect you"; // reference
```

the similarity result would be `1`.

Now, what if we want to compare a smaller part of the sentence with the reference string?

**so if we have these:**

```
  var str1 = "I was sent to earth"; // user input
  var str2 = "I was sent to earth to protect you"; // reference
```

**or these:**

```
  var str1 = "I was sent to earth"; // user input
  var str2 = "to protect you I was sent to earth"; // reference
```

**the expected similarity result should be `1`.**

Here is my code:

```js
function checkSimilarity(){
  var str1 = "I was sent to earth";
  var str2 = "I was sent to earth to protect you";
  console.log(similarity(str1, str2));
}

function similarity(s1, s2) {
      var longer = s1;
      var shorter = s2;
      if (s1.length < s2.length) {
        longer = s2;
        shorter = s1;
      }
      var longerLength = longer.length;
      if (longerLength == 0) {
        return 1.0;
      }
      return (longerLength - editDistance(longer, shorter)) / parseFloat(longerLength);
    }

    function editDistance(s1, s2) {
      s1 = s1.toLowerCase();
      s2 = s2.toLowerCase();

      var costs = new Array();
      for (var i = 0; i <= s1.length; i++) {
        var lastValue = i;
        for (var j = 0; j <= s2.length; j++) {
          if (i == 0)
            costs[j] = j;
          else {
            if (j > 0) {
              var newValue = costs[j - 1];
              if (s1.charAt(i - 1) != s2.charAt(j - 1))
                newValue = Math.min(Math.min(newValue, lastValue),
                  costs[j]) + 1;
              costs[j - 1] = lastValue;
              lastValue = newValue;
            }
          }
        }
        if (i > 0)
          costs[s2.length] = lastValue;
      }
      return costs[s2.length];
    }
checkSimilarity();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what about "b" in "abc" ? Is that 1 too? What are the exact rules? Levenstein distance without addition? And then divide by string length?

Comment: "b" in "abc" ? Is not 1 because I want to compare words... and I can't understand the rest of your question ;)

Comment: Then "some example" and "example" ... whats their similarity?

Comment: "I was sent to earth" and "to protect I was sent to earth etc" are 100 percent similar if the first one is the reference and the second sentence is the user input ... I want to check sentence similarity!

Comment: And what about "some sentence" and "sentence some" ?

Comment: it should be between 1 and 0 ... not 1 because it's not exactly the same and not 0 because it's not totally different... maybe 0.5

Comment: maybe .... How should we write code for "maybe" ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the patienceDiffPlus algorithm ( see https://github.com/jonTrent/PatienceDiff ), which can be used to compare two similar arrays of strings.  Usually this algorithm is used to ferret out the changes in an updated computer program, but in your case, can be used to compare the words in the sentences.  Specifically, this algorithm searches for the longest common subsequence (LCS) between the arrays of words, and reports the number of words inserted, deleted, likely moved, and by calculation, the number of similar words in a common sequence.

In terms of calculating the measure of equality, based on your examples it appears that extra words in the reference are not held against the measure.  Not knowing, though, the full spectrum of reference sentences that you're going to compare the user input against, I would suggest a calculation along the following lines:

*Similarity = (Result.lines.length - Result.lineCountMoved - Result.lineCountDeleted - Result.lineCountInserted) / (Result.lines.length - Result.lineCountMoved)*

Using your first example...

```
var str1 = "I was sent to earth"; // user input
var str2 = "I was sent to earth to protect you"; // reference
var compare12 = patienceDiffPlus(str1.split(" "), str2.split(" "));
console.log(compare12);
// {lines: Array(8), lineCountDeleted: 0, lineCountInserted: 3, lineCountMoved: 0}
```

...indicates that str2 had 3 additional words inserted, and 5 words were equal and in a common sequence.  The similarity measure is (8 - 0 - 3) / (8 - 0) or 0.625.  Now, using your second example...

```
var str3 = "I was sent to earth"; // user input
var str4 = "to protect you I was sent to earth"; // reference
var compare34 = patienceDiffPlus(str3.split(" "), str4.split(" "));
console.log(compare34)
// {lines: Array(8), lineCountDeleted: 0, lineCountInserted: 3, lineCountMoved: 0}
```

...again indicates that str4 had 3 additional words inserted, and 5 words were equal and in a common sequence.  Like before, the similarity measure is 0.625.  Now for a more complex example...

```
var str5 = "I was sent to the earth to protect you";  // user input
var str6 = "to protect you I was sent to planet earth"; // reference
var compare56 = patienceDiffPlus(str5.split(" "), str6.split(" "));
console.log(compare56);
// {lines: Array(13), lineCountDeleted: 1, lineCountInserted: 1, lineCountMoved: 3}
//   lineCountDeleted: 1
//   lineCountInserted: 1
//   lineCountMoved: 3
//   lines: Array(13)
//     0: {line: "to", aIndex: 10, bIndex: 0, moved: true}
//     1: {line: "protect", aIndex: 11, bIndex: 1, moved: true}
//     2: {line: "you", aIndex: 12, bIndex: 2, moved: true}
//     3: {line: "I", aIndex: 0, bIndex: 3}
//     4: {line: "was", aIndex: 1, bIndex: 4}
//     5: {line: "sent", aIndex: 2, bIndex: 5}
//     6: {line: "to", aIndex: 3, bIndex: 6}
//     7: {line: "the", aIndex: 4, bIndex: -1}
//     8: {line: "planet", aIndex: -1, bIndex: 7}
//     9: {line: "earth", aIndex: 5, bIndex: 8}
//     10: {line: "to", aIndex: 6, bIndex: -1, moved: true}
//     11: {line: "protect", aIndex: 7, bIndex: -1, moved: true}
//     12: {line: "you", aIndex: 8, bIndex: -1, moved: true}
//     length: 13
```

...which indicates that str5 had one word deleted/missing relative to str6 ("the"), str6 had one word inserted ("planet"), and 3 words were likely moved ("to", "protect", & "you").  In this case, the similarity measure is (13 - 3 - 1 - 1) / (13 - 3) or 0.800.

Presumably you have an array of reference sentences that you plan to compare the user input against, in which case you will need to run the user input through the patienceDiffPlus algorithm against all the reference sentences, and select the highest similarity measure.

That being said, you will need to work through a larger sampling of expected user input against your reference sentences to tweak the means of measuring similarity that best fits your application.  Additionally, you might find that you have to remove punctuation, set everything to lower case, maybe remove common prepositions, etc to boil the user input down to the basics to assist in the matching process...

Hope this helps.